# How to install Debian, not using ISO?

Tags: debian, installation, usb-flash-drive, installer

ATA-ATAPI CDROMs are way too old and complicated technology, differs from flash chips. Working with isos was always kinda painful, required either overwriting installation media, or some drive emulation techniques. I want to learn tech and move on to convenience.

Earlier I did like following: I just tried to write somehow iso contents onto USB drive. Almost always that produced installation USB media, except drive content was killed. So now I want only to "add" OS installers to USB drive.

Stick has syslinux installed, along with some useful stuff, which is strictly prohibited to erase. For Debian I've looked for ["net-boot" installer](http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/) I am thinking that this is kind of installer that usually downloads its `vmlinuz` and `initrd` images via BOOTP/TFTP, and everything other - via Internet (using wget or whatever).

There is no much difference in pxelinux and syslinux, so I was very happy that I may add Debian installer just "that easily" without killing all the data. I downloaded those two, but ran into error: "Installation step failed: load installer components from an installer ISO" [image]

I am stumbled, dont know what to do next. Why do I need iso, if i alredy found a way and loaded kernel with debian installer to RAM? And installer could just download everything from internet mirrors? (As it usually did previously).

---

To be strict, my question is:

**What is minimal file subset nesesary to have on usb drive, in order to install minimal debian system to sata drive?**

---

PS:

- x64 PC boots only from USB 2.0 stick, and have sata drive, and working internet connection attached. No way to boot from network, or use optical/any other boot media.
- USB stick is formatted as FAT32
- usb stick bootloader is SYSLINUX (using any other boot loaders is prohibited).
- nesesary files are to be copied only by hands (no automated tools to create portabl installations, no "write iso image to usb")
- after a config tweak, system should install from internet to hdd just fine.
- deleting any single file from usb must result to wrecked installation.

Comment: Are you sure you want USB installers?? read about PXE; i.e. Serva

Comment: @Pat YES I am 100% sure in what I want. I am not interested in PXE, as well as booting from CDs, DVDs, BDs, external hard drives, or anything, other that plain USB 2.0 stick (formatted as FAT32).. So I can only close my eyes, and repeat my strict and very exact question: **What is a minimal file subset should I put onto USB drive, in order to install Debian "from internet" to sata drive?** (using that only USB drive plus Internet connection). Btw, as for today, question is NOT solved.

Comment: Good answer could be either example of such a file list, or a link to such list, or a link to an article, explaining "what is going on inside installer, what files does it seeks on a bootable media", or at least a hint on how to invesigate this process..

Comment: If the netboot initramfs expects to find a PXE environment, this simply cannot be made to work, period. Use the Debian minimal installation medium.

Comment: @DanielB "If" does not fit. Does it expect or not? Is it possible to use it or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are struggling in finding an answer because your requirement is not common;
most people today do not like/want booting from pendrives and prefer a simple PXE server approach (i.e. Serva); it's way faster and allows handling multi-asset install scenarios in a simpler manner than just using pendrives.

Regarding your last bullet point of requirements they just cannot be simultaneously met.

But if you want to install Debian just booting a minimal kernel from an USB stick and the rest from Internet then your answer is a [netinst](https://www.debian.org/distrib/netinst) CD image (generally 150-300 MB, varies by architecture).
Move the corresponding ISO to your pendrive with i.e. [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/) and boot it on your target PC.

If you are curious about the Install booting process it is something like booting a kernel, then the **kernel** loads an **initrd** that contains the **init** script wich in Debian's case ends up loading [**debconf**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_configuration_system) (Debian installer). 
**debconf** is in charge of conducting all the Debian install process by parsing a series of install commands received either from:

1. The kernel command line at boot,
2. The automated [preseed](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Preseed) file, or
3. User manual input.

In case of a Network Install debconf (among other data) will certainly require the IP/URL of a valid Debian repository where Debian components are located.

debconf will finish its job with a installed Debian system.

Note: the screenshot in your question shows debconf in action displaying in this case an install error message.

Debian derivatives (Ubuntu, MInt, etc) use virtually the same install system.
Non Debian distros and their derivatives (RHEL, Fedora, SuSEE etc.) use different but similar install systems.

Comment: Thanks for useful info,t in a 'home' environment sometimes its hard to create pxe environment, due to absence of second PC.. Pendrive is more superior in terms of "can run it everywhere from home to data center" ;-)

Comment: I wonder who are those "most people" installing through PXE server is a pure hell. I've never got this working in my life.

Comment: Probably you just used the wrong tool. The professional approach for OS installation is PXE based. Microsoft i.e. offers WDS, MDT, and SCCM, yes they are not simple but today it is unthinkable distributing PC not imaged with PXE based solutions. Also you have way simpler PXE tools that let you Install capture and deploy OSs in a simple maner; [Serva](https://www.vercot.com/~serva/an/WindowsPXE1.html)

Answer (score 1):

For Debian, you only really need the `netboot` kernel and initrd files, since the current Debian installer is modular: the initrd file contains the first part that will load the rest directly from a Debian repository. And of course SYSLINUX or some other bootloader that is capable of loading them.

There are two versions of the netboot initramfs file: `initrd-gtk.gz` includes the new graphical installer, while `initrd.gz` contains the text-mode installer. Pick one or the other.

Your problem of the "load installer components from an installer ISO" step failing indicates one of the following things:

- perhaps you did not give the installer a permission to connect to the network, so it attempted to find a local installation media instead? (The Debian installer will always prefer loading the most up-to-date packets from the Debian repositories if at all possible.)
- perhaps the installer failed to detect your NIC? (Get the latest version of the official netboot installer kernel & initramfs packages from [here](http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/debian-installer/amd64/) instead of using a possibly-old version from an ISO image)
- or perhaps your NIC requires firmware, which is a non-Free Software component, and so is something Debian handles somewhat with a ten-foot pole. (Downloading the necessary firmware package(s) from the `non-free` section of the Debian repository, and placing them to either the root directory or the `/firmware` sub-directory of the USB stick should fix that problem.)

Remember that Debian follows the common convention of providing installer logs and a root shell on other virtual consoles, so when you reach the error message you pictured, you can press <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> and activate a shell prompt, so you can use commands like `ip link show`, `lsmod` and `lspci` to see whether or not your NIC was successfully detected, for example.

Comment: Thanks for useful info, about how things work. And I really forgot for a moment, about virtual console existence! That would simplify things alot

Answer (score 0):

yesterday i had to install debian fast and only had spare extended partition space, but i was able to use GRML as a working space, which i had already installed on a small primary partition of the drive. But it also could be booted from a CD .... or as a hack just flashed to the beginning of the drive, and then do the repartitioning with debian installer later, when it's running ...

... for my install of debian-10.9.0-amd64, i took the first DVD image (debian-10.9.0-amd64-DVD1.iso) and directly copied it to a logical partition i made at the end of an extended partition on the same drive:

```
cat debian-10.9.0-amd64-DVD1.iso > /dev/sda7
```

... then i rebooted GRML and from GRUB menu chose to edit a boot command, and made this command (after establishing that the iso image is written at (hd0,msdos7)):

```
 set root=(hd0,msdos7)
        linux /install.amd/vmlinuz
        initrd /install.amd/initrd.gz
```

... then hit f10 to boot it ... and the installer was running fine, with just one hitch, so eventually discovered that i needed to drop to shell in the installer, and manually do:

```
umount /cdrom
mount /dev/sda7 /cdrom
exit
```

... and then back in the installer steps, and completed the install fine

i guess that is similar to the answer above, but perhaps simpler, once you have some environment / OS open to make the copy, and access to grub boot ...

( also, i think i am using much newer version(s) than you are )

... but i don't see why it cannot apply to a smaller image image also which will then get the files it needs from whatever network you give the installer